# Distinguishing bluetooth devices with android devices having same name

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have an Android app that connects to a specific type of Heart Rate Bluetooth device that continuously returns new Heart rate data. The device has a predefined name that always starts with "HRxxxx" and by using the `if (device.getName().startsWith("HR"))` I am able to distinguish it from the other devices (i.e. headsets) and start a connection.

However, I have an issue, if two or more people are using the same type of device, how will they be able to discern which is their device (i.e. at the gym while running next to each other). Since both devices will start with "HR" they might connect to another person's device. As a result, are there any other approaches/ways in which I could use to get a specific device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use mac id of the bluetooth device. mac address is unique for every device.

Comment: well... i will save my device's Mac ID and look it up from a list of saved Mac ID's every time a device gets connected, so if the Mac ID is there the application will run, otherwise it will not. Thx for your answer!